# NameError: name 'z' is not defined (Logistic-Regression, Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, logistic-regression

Titanic Survival Classification
Build a logistic regression model to predict whether a passenger on the titanic would survive based on the amount of money they paid for the ticket

There are two data files for this question.

shiptrain.txt -> Use this to train your model
shiptest.txt -> Use this to test your model
Format of the data file

x1 which represents the ticket price (First column)
y which respresents if that passenger survived or not 1 = survived, 0 = did not survive (2nd Column)
Output the following

Weights from the model
Minimum Cost
Accuracy of the model
Prediction for a ticket price of 20
Predcition for a ticket price of 60
Prediction for a ticket price of 1000

#FILL IN THE CODE to accomplish that task

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import scipy.optimize as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

import os
path = os.getcwd() + '\shiptrain.txt' 

x1=[]
y=[]
file = open(path,"r")
while True:
line = file.readline()
if not line:
    break
else:
    values = line.split(",")
    x1.append(float(values[0]))
    y.append(float(values[1].rstrip("\n")))
file.close()

def h(X,theta):  
z = X*theta.T

sigmoid = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
return sigmoid
def J(theta, X, y):
theta = np.matrix(theta)
X = np.matrix(X)
y = np.matrix(y)
z = X*theta.T
sigmoid = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
first = np.multiply(-y, np.log(h(X,theta)))
second = np.multiply((1-y),np.log(1-h(X,theta)))
total = np.sum(first - second) / (len(X))

m = len(x1)
x1 = np.array(x1)
ones = np.ones((808,1))
x = np.column_stack((ones,x1))
y = np.array([y]).T
 theta = np.zeros(2)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2676/2204457314.py in <module>
 26     z = X*theta.T
 27 
---> 28 sigmoid = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
 29 return sigmoid
 30 def J(theta, X, y):

NameError: name 'z' is not defined
```

How?

Comment: first fix indentations. Indentations can change everything so code without indentations is useless for us.